# Ubuntu 14.04 wants to update same package every day

Tags: 14.04, apt, updates, update-manager

I've problem with updating. Ubuntu 14.04 wants to update same packages every day. It's Boot repair (which I installed) and hostApd (which was installed by default) but I do not want them to update because newer versions screw things up. I tried to update it once, and I was told that update is successful. But next time I rebooted, it still wanted to update it.

So I decided to prevent it from updating with

```
apt-mark hold "package_name"
```

It did not help, packages are still shown in update program, and anything else is not there so I have to update manually by `apt-get update`. Any idea how to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below to disbale the automatic update by adding the below in /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic,

```
sudo -e /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic

APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "0";
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I even rebooted but packages are still shown in update program. When I use sudo apt-get upgrade, it works fine, it just shows which packages are on hold, and which are going to be upgraded.